# My code of plotting a two-variable function is too slow

Tags: functions, numerics, mathematical-optimization, plotting

I have a code in which my complicated function to be plotted is F(x,p). I would like to graph it for 5 values of p equal to 10^7, 10^8, 10^9, 10^10 and 10^11 for x values between 0.01 and 0.99. All five plots need to be on the same plot. I am using the following line which runs forever. Do you have a much better idea to get it faster?
Appreciate your help,

```
F[u_] := ((3.14159265359*u^2*(0.251)^2)/(24.*(1. - u^2)) (1./u (u^4 - 18.*u^2 + 33.)* Log[(1. + u)/(1. - u)] + 31.*u^2 - 59.) + (32.*3.14159265359*u*(0.251)^3)/(1. - u^2)^2*(7./(1536.*3.14159265359)*(12.*u*(Log[8.*u^2])^2 - 366./7.*u*Log[8.*u^2] + (11.*3.14159265359^2)/42.) + u*(0.108068 + u^2*(-0.114997*Log[8.*u^2] + 0.042863) + 0.131429*u^4*Log[8.*u^2] + (1. - u^2)^2*(0.0438768*Log[1. - u^2] - 0.0760996*(Log[1. - u^2])^2) + (1. - u^2)*(-0.0165878*Log[1. - u^2] - 0.158246*(Log[1. - u^2])^2)) - (1. - u^2)^2/(1024.*3.14159265359)*(Log[(1. + u)/(1. - u)] - 2.*u)) + (Log[2.]*u (0.251)^3)/(768.*(1. - u^2)^2)*(2.*(1. - u^2)*(59.*u^4 - 316.*u^2 - 31.)*Log[(1. + u)/(1. - u)] + 12.*(1. - u^2)*(u^4 - 18.*u^2 + 33.)*(PolyLog[2., (2.*u)/(1. + u)] - PolyLog[2., (-2.*u)/(1. - u)]) - 6.*(1. - u^2)*(u^4 + 14.*u^2 + 17.)*((Log[(1. + u)/2.])^2 - (Log[(1. - u)/2.])^2 + 2.*PolyLog[2., (1. + u)/2.] - 2.*PolyLog[2., (1. - u)/2.]) - (4.*u)/ 15.*(7449.*u^4 - 11570.*u^2 + 4845.) + (3.14159265359*u*(1. - u^2))/ 16.*(1./u*(u^4 - 18.*u^2 + 33.)*Log[(1. + u)/(1. - u)] + 31.*u^2 - 59.)*Log[(1. - u^2)/(4.*u^2)]));

Umax[x_, y_, p_] := (1. - 3.46515/(y*(y + x)*p))^0.5;


W[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[F[u], {u, 0, Umax[x, y, p]}, AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 5];


dist[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := (0.38937966)^-1*x*g[y]*g[x + y];

H[x_, y_, p_] := dist[x, y]*W[x, y, p];

ymin[x_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := 0.5*x*((1. + 13.8606/(x^2*p))^0.5 - 1.);

ymax[x_?NumericQ] := 1 - x;

myFunction[x_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[H[x, y, p], {y, ymin[x, p], ymax[x]}, AccuracyGoal -> 2, PrecisionGoal -> 5];

mynewFunction[x_, p_] := Re[myFunction[x, p]];

ListPlot[Evaluate[Table[F[x, p], {p, {10^7, 10^8, 10^9, 10^10, 10^11}},{x, 0.01, 0.9901, 0.01}]],
    PlotStyle -> {Orange, Red, Green, Blue, Black}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: What is $F[x,p]$?

Comment: F(u) is a very complicated function of u. Umax is a function of x,y and p. W(x,y,p)=integral(F(u),{u,0,Umax). g(t) is a ListInterpolation of some data. dist(x,y)= x*g(y)*g(x+y). H(x,y,p)=dist(x,y)*W(x,y,p), Ymin(x,p) and Ymax(x). myFunction(x,p)=integral(H(x,y,p),{y,Ymin,Ymax}) and this last function is the one I am talking about.

Comment: As @k_v states in his "Answer" (which I can't see will provide any benefit), we can't help you much without seeing *F[x,p]*.  How long does it take to plot a single *F[x,p0]*?

Comment: First check if the slow part is already contained in `Table[F[x, p], {p, {10^7, 10^8, 10^9, 10^10, 10^11}},
   {x, 0.01, 0.9901, 0.01}]]`. Then narrow it down by reducing the list.

Comment: Yes, even plotting a single plot f(x, 10^7) is running forever.

Comment: And, yes. The slow part is already in Table[..]

Comment: Here is my entire code. As you can see, it is very complicated. However, I am assuming there should be a faster way to get the final plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may try this, without explicit defenition of F[x,p] it's hard to reccomend something

```
Plot[F[x,#]&/@{10^7, 10^8, 10^9, 10^10, 10^11},{x,0,1}]
```

Comment: I applied it and it is still running. Hopefully it will stop sooner than my previous code.